# How do I search (SELECT and WHERE) in firebase and put them to recycle view

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I'm trying to retrieve data from (Confesses table) on firebase database, but not all data, I want to make a condition on it and show the result in recycleView, it worked for me, I retrieve the specific data that I want but it call an empty row in the recycleView ...

I have 3 object in my firebase database, two object achieve the condition that I want, the other not achieve it ... so when I'll show the data, just the two object must be appear, unfortunately all the object appear, but the object that not achieving the condition appear but empty ... see the picture below

[image: This picture shows the problem]

Initialisation :

```
rView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.confess_list);
    rView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    rView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Confesses");
    setupAdapter();
    rView.setAdapter(mPostAdapter);
```

here is where I put the condition

```
private void setupAdapter() {
    mPostAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Confess, PostViewHolder>(
            Confess.class,
            R.layout.sample_confess,
            PostViewHolder.class,
            mFirebaseDatabase
    ) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(PostViewHolder viewHolder, final Confess model, int position) {
            db = new SQLiteHandler(getApplicationContext());
            final HashMap<String, String> user = db.getUserDetails();

            if (model.getIdReceiver().equals(user.get("idUser"))){
                viewHolder.setContent(StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(model.getConfessContent()));
                viewHolder.setDate(model.getCreated_at());
            }


        }
    };
}
```

ViewHolder class

```
public static class PostViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public EmojiconTextView emojyView;
    public TextView dateView;


    public PostViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        emojyView = (EmojiconTextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.emojicon_text_viewMain);
        dateView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.c_date);
    }


    public void setContent(String content) {
        emojyView.setText(content);
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        dateView.setText(date);
    }
}
```

[image: Here is my data structure]

Comment: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/10/queries-part-1-common-sql-queries.html?m=1

Comment: You need to filter the database reference before you put it in the adapter, but you've not provided the structure of the database in your question, so it's hard to help

Comment: Hi dude, thanks for your answer ... here is my data structure 
http://imgh.us/structure.png

please help meeee

Comment: I edited the question, you can found the data structure in the bottom

Comment: idReceiver must be equals to the authenticated user id (I get it from SQLite table "user.get("idUser") )

Condition : model.getIdReceiver().equals(user.get("idUser"))

Comment: the idea it's simple, like a post app ... I write a post and I have an activity to see what I wrote, example : (select post where post.idWriter == myId_InTheSession)

Comment: It's too late at that point, you've already gotten all the data from Firebase within the adapter. You must query your sqlite database before you create `mFirebaseDatabase` and then grab only the data for that userId

Comment: I did a query but FirebaseRecyclerAdapter don't accept Query in the parameters ... do you have an example for this operation :/

Comment: You simply need to update `mFirebaseDatabase` before you ever hand it to the adapter

Comment: how ... give me the code please 
cos I don't know how to apply WHERE on the date using firebase databese

Comment: The first link I added shows how to do a WHERE... however, you might be better off not using FirebaseUI and simply constructing your own Recyclerview in which you can use the if statement you already have

Comment: FirebaseRecyclerAdapter don't accept Query : http://imgh.us/pr..png

Comment: Alternatively, instead of storing a flat list of "confesses", you instead store users as the top element, and confesses as a child of that. That's how I would store your data unless you ever needed all the confesses at once

Comment: Umm... `DatabaseReference extends Query`... Your error is saying your **field** is a DatabaseReference, but the method `equalTo` returned a `Query`. The adapter isn't the problem there

Comment: And for any `Query`, you simply call `getRef()`. Check the API documentation. https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query

Comment: So how can I reference to those object how achieve the condition

Comment: Personally, I would invert the database to store users as the top element (and then `equalTo` will work), and that holds a child of confesses, which you directly access or `orderByChild("created_at")`

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this problem by adding a filter to my 'FirebaseRecyclerAdapter'
Now it's working :D

```
mPostAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Confess, PostViewHolder>(
            Confess.class,
            R.layout.sample_confess,
            PostViewHolder.class,
            mFirebaseDatabase.orderByChild("idReceiver").equalTo(userId)
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

to make query in Firebase will be Like

```
     mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
        .getReference().child("Confesses")
        .orderByChild("YOUR_FIELD").equalTo("Value")
       .getRef()
```

**But** You can`t query AND , OR  .. which mean there will be only one **orderByChild** in your Query

and there are more Queries You can Use Like

**.startAt("  ")**

**.endAt("")**

**.limitToFirst()**

**.limitToLast()**

Comment: Wouldn't you want to order by date? Then how exactly does the equalTo here filter out other user ids? Isn't that comparing the ID of the confesses?

Comment: .child("Confesses").orderby("idReciver").equalto("lkasdfjkl")

try it    , it like where(uid == sdlkfj)

Comment: Why would you ever need to order by an ID instead of a date?

Comment: caue he want to filter by ID not date

Comment: All I'm saying is that ordering is pointless for an equality. `child("Confesses").equalTo(userId, "idReceiver").orderByChild("created_at")` looks more correct to me.

Comment: You are Right , you totally Right :)

Comment: @cricket_007: you seem to misunderstand how the `equalTo()` with two arguments work. The second argument is not the child to filter on, it is the **key** of the child to start at in case there are more children with `userId`. It is only useful in pagination scenarios and cannot be used to filter on two different child properties.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Got it :) Thanks for clarifying. I do find it strange that ordering is first necessary in order to perform equality, though.

Comment: Same here. But at this point I've accepted that it's simply how the API works.